# Problem with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/[0-9#%@_$&!?^\/|*<>]+/i
```

which is not supposed to accept letters. It does accept letters when letters are not entered at the first place.

e.g.:
it finds a match if I enter "123e" (but should not because there is a letter)

What is the problem in my regex?

Thanks

Comment: If it isn't supposed to match any letters, why did you add the `/i` flag? Just wondering `:)`

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it did work with ^ and $ (/^[0-9#%@_$&!?^/|*<>]+$/i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex checks if there is **one or more** of the list characters you specified -- and that's true for `123e`.

It doesn't check if the string contains **only those**.

You might want to edit your regex, so it looks like this :

```
/^[0-9#%@_$&!?^/|*<>]+$/i
```

Where I've added the two following [**anchors**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) :

- `^` indicating "*beginning of string / line*"
- `$` indicating "*end of string / line*"

Which means the regex will check if your string starts with one of your characters, end with one of those, and contains those.

Answer (score 2):

Use start and end anchors...

```
/^[\d#%@_$&!?^/|*<>]+\z/i
```

`^` means the start of the string and `\z` means the end of the string. The commonly used `$` for the end of the string will allow a trailing `\n`. This is not always appropriate.

Comment: Will `$` really allow `\n` without the `/m` flag?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole string to contain only the characters you specified in the regex, you'll need to anchor it:

```
/^[0-9#%@_$&!?^\/|*<>]+$/i
```

Otherwise, it looks for the specified character class *anywhere in the string*: as long as there is at least one of those in it, the regex would match.

Comment: what about `.`, `\`` and `~` for example?

Comment: what about them? the OP says his RE was not supposed to match characters, not that that was the only thing he didn't want to match.

Comment: as I understand from the question, he wants the regex to match *any* character that is *not* a letter

Answer (score 0):

Start the regex with `^` and end it with `$`. That will make it exclusive.

`^` stands for beginning of the line.

`$` stands for end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

try by simply negating the character class that represents all letters:

```
/[^a-z^A-Z]+/
```